# $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$ || Is there any easy method to show that the sequence [$f^n(0)$] is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

$f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$

$f^n(0)$ denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$ at the point $0$.

Is there any easy method to show that the sequence [$f^n(0)$] is unbounded?

Comment: $f^{(n)}(0)$ could simply be calculated. Then $f^{(n)}(0)$ is bounded or not would be clear.

Comment: It's easy to calculate the Taylor series of $f$, use that to find $f^{(n)}(0)$

Comment: @xbh Oh! You can find the general derivative of this function! How?

Comment: No, I have only said that $\color {red}{f^{n}(0)}$ could be calculated, not the general derivative functions.

Comment: @xbh I am suggesting that it is not an EASY method.

Comment: Also you could observe that $\arctan$ has a singularity at $x=\pm i$ which implies the Taylor series has a finite radius of convergence, so the sequence of derivitives at any point (not just 0) must be unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Direct method [no Taylor series here].

First we know that 
$$
f’(x) = \frac 1 {1+x^2}  \implies (1 + x^2) f’(x) = 1.
$$ 
Now take the $n$-th derivative: by the Leibniz rule, 
$$
(1 + x^2)f^{(n+1)}(x) + 2nx f^{(n)}(x) + n(n-1) f^{(n-1)}(x) = 0.
$$
Plug $x = 0$ into the equation above, we have 
$$
f^{(n+1)} (0) + n(n-1) f^{(n-1)} (0) = 0.
$$
Since $f^{(0)} (0)= 0, f^{(1)} (0) = 1$, $f^{(2n)} (0) = 0$, and
$$
f^{(2n+1)}(0) = - 2n (2n-1) f^{(2n-1)}(0) = 2n(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)f^{(2n-3)}(0) = \cdots = (2n)! (-1)^n. 
$$

This method is not as quick as the one using Taylor series, but feasible.

Comment: Will we not get using Taylor series?@xbh

Comment: @cmi No, i did not mean that. Taylor series would be a quicker method.